# WebService WCF - Cannot obtain metadata

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an WCF Service, and it works in localhost, but when published to an IIS server, I wasn't able to access it's methods anymore, the error message was that

> "This assembly does not allow partially trusted callers"

Then, I added the following to the Web.config file:

```
<trust level="Full" originUrl=""/>
```

Now, I receive this error message:

> Cannot obtain Metadata from http://wheremyserviceispublished.net/Service.svc
>   If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you
>   have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at
>   the specified address.

Does anybody have an clue on how to solve these problems?

Comment: Do you have mex endpoint enabled? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-configure-a-custom-ws-metadata-exchange-binding

Comment: This link is better https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/publishing-metadata-endpoints

Comment: <endpoint address="mex"  
              binding="mexHttpBinding"  
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />

Comment: I added this line and still receive the same error.

Comment: put your full endpoint and with bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you publish wcf service in IIS, the default configuration has disclosed the metadata information.

```
<!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

You could also assign the metadata address in httpGetUrl attribute.

If you want to disclose the metadata information on the endpoint configuration. Try to follow this.

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
```

---

```
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="svbehavior">
          <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
```

And then apply the behavior on the endpoint so that It could take effect.

```
<service name="WcfService4.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="svbehavior">
```

Feel free to contact me if the problem still exists.